# Misaligned Bootstrap Carousel Image in Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, carousel

I'm creating [a simple HTML template](http://zulhfreelancer.com/projects/omar/) using Bootstrap 3.
I have problem with the Carousel. The images didn't align properly when viewed in Firefox browser.

Screenshot using Firefox browser:
[image]

Screenshot using Google Chrome & Opera is OK:
[image]

My Carousel code:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active">
        </li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1">
        </li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2">
        </li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="img/1.jpeg">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>
                Example headline.
              </h1>
              <p>
                Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.
              </p>
              <p>
                <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">
                  Call to Action
                </a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="img/2.jpeg">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>
                Another example headline.
              </h1>
              <p>
                Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.
              </p>
              <p>
                <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">
                  Register Now
                </a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="img/3.jpeg">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>
                One more for good measure.
              </h1>
              <p>
                Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.
              </p>
              <p>
                <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">
                  Read Blog
                </a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left">
        </span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right">
        </span>
      </a>
    </div>
```

I already include jQuery in `<head>` tag and the transitions is working. Just have problem with the image position.

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the carousel in a .container div. This will center it along with keeping it consistent with your content.

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active">
        </li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1">
        </li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2">
        </li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="img/1.jpeg">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>
                Example headline.
              </h1>
              <p>
                Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.
              </p>
              <p>
                <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">
                  Call to Action
                </a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="img/2.jpeg">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>
                Another example headline.
              </h1>
              <p>
                Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.
              </p>
              <p>
                <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">
                  Register Now
                </a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="img/3.jpeg">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>
                One more for good measure.
              </h1>
              <p>
                Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.
              </p>
              <p>
                <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">
                  Read Blog
                </a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left">
        </span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right">
        </span>
      </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok thanks. I just add clearfix to solve the problem. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Adding a clearfix solved the problem in Firefox for me asswell.

```
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide clearfix" data-ride="carousel">
```